# How to match all multi- and single line messages with a regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a lot of logfiles which contain a lot of muti and single line messages. I want to parse these messages and therefore I would like to filter all individual messages from the files. I am trying to match all multiline strings in the log file with a regular expression. I can't figure out how to make it also match the last message from the string. Each new message starts with a date. The following example shows what I was trying to do:

```
import regex as re
multi = """
2015-08-31T23:33:35.423Z   INFO: disp24 [  process]  (Log.java:124) [toSACLogger] - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LifeSignRequest>
    <Header>
        <MessageTime>2015-08-29T05:41:24.0Z</MessageTime>
        <Source>
            <ProcessID>008</ProcessID>
        </Source>
        <Target>
            <ProcessID>FSM</ProcessID>
        </Target>
    </Header>
    <Sequence>9298</Sequence>
</LifeSignRequest>


2015-08-31T23:33:35.440Z   INFO: disp0 [handleResponse]  (HttpClient.java:320) [HttpClient.253_1]no connection or empty contents
2015-08-31T23:33:35.440Z   INFO: disp0 [  process]  (Log.java:124) [toMCSLogger] - <?xml version="1.0"?>
<LifeSignResponse>
  <Header>
    <MessageTime>2015-08-31T23:33:35.000Z</MessageTime>
    <Source>
      <ProcessID>FSM</ProcessID>
    </Source>
    <Target>
      <ProcessID>MCS</ProcessID>
      <InstanceID>3006</InstanceID>
    </Target>
  </Header>
  <Signature>9298</Signature>
</LifeSignResponse>

2015-08-31T23:33:37.164Z   INFO: disp23 [  process]  (Log.java:124) [toSACLogger] - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LifeSignRequest>
    <Header>
        <MessageTime>2015-08-31T23:33:36.0Z</MessageTime>
        <Source>
            <ProcessID>014</ProcessID>
        </Source>
        <Target>
            <ProcessID>FSM</ProcessID>
        </Target>
    </Header>
    <Sequence>110</Sequence>
</LifeSignRequest>


2015-08-31T23:33:37.189Z   INFO: disp8 [handleResponse]  (HttpClient.java:320) [HttpClient.253_7]no connection or empty contents
2015-08-31T23:33:37.189Z   INFO: disp8 [  process]  (Log.java:124) [toMCSLogger] - <?xml version="1.0"?>
<LifeSignResponse>
  <Header>
    <MessageTime>2015-08-31T23:33:37.000Z</MessageTime>
    <Source>
      <ProcessID>FSM</ProcessID>
    </Source>
    <Target>
      <ProcessID>MCS</ProcessID>
      <InstanceID>3005</InstanceID>
    </Target>
  </Header>
  <Signature>110</Signature>
</LifeSignResponse>
"""

data = re.findall(r'^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.*?)(?=^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})', multi, re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
for row in data:
    print row
```

The regular expression in the example above will match all messages except for the last message.

My question is: "How can I match all messages in the string in the example above with a regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Add `|\Z` to your lookahead](https://regex101.com/r/uY8fP3/1):

```
^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.*?)(?=^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|\Z)
```

Your expression is failing to match the last group because it is using a lazy dot-match-all which is dependent on your lookahead finding something to match up to (otherwise it will be lazy and match 0 characters). `\Z` is defined as the end of the string (because `$` will just match the end of the line) and will give the lazy match something else to look for if there are no other timestamps to find.